# Can't compile swift program from a 1 year old tutorial

Tags: xcode, swift

Very low level question but;

Why wont this compile for me? I copied it down exactly from a tutorial and it worked before I updated my xcode to a newer version to do things later in the tutorial but I guess it updated too far ahead. Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let Mainball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    Mainball.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    Mainball.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.width / 2, y: scene!.frame.height / 2)



    self.addChild(Mainball)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    }
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to compile for me.  What version of Xcode and what error are you getting?

Comment: 7.3.1 and I get a build failed error. On the tutorial it makes a ball in the middle of the screen. I just noticed I have problems in my game controller.swift after the update.

Comment: The error was that I didn't update my gameviewcontroller.swift to compensate for updating my xcode. I just took a default one from another new swift program and that fixed it. Thanks for letting me know it compiled and that that wasn't the error.